# matplotlib.pyplotのplotできれいな曲線が書けません。

Tags: python, r, matplotlib

python初心者なのですが、曲線（√(1-x^2)）がうまく描けません。二番目の図みたいにするにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
x=rand(100) #100個の一様乱数
plt.plot(numpy.sqrt(1-x**2),x)
```

[image: python]

[image: r]

二番目の図のようなきれいな曲線にしたいですが、どうプログラムを書けばいいのでしょうか？曲線用の関数などあったら教えてください。
補足：二番目の図はｒで書きました。

```
 #R
 x=runif(100) #100個の一様乱数
 curve(sqrt(1-x^2))
```

Comment: `x` をソートしてからプロットする必要があります。`x = numpy.sort(numpy.random.rand(100))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず，なぜそのような出力になっているかと言うと，Numpyの配列の順番に点同士を結んでいるからで，sortすればよいというのは一つの回答ではあります．
一方で，そういったプロットを行う場合には， `linspace` という関数を使った方がよいです．これは，指定した区間上の等間隔な数列を得るための関数です．
例えば，`numpy.linspace(0, 1, 11)`とすると，以下のような配列が得られます．

```
[0.  0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1. ]
```

参考まで，`linspace`を用いたコード例と結果を示します．

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

x = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 100)
plt.plot(x, numpy.sqrt(1-x**2))
plt.show()
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

参考：https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html

### 追記

`plot`の引数はx,yの順なので，Rの`curve(func(x))`と等価なことをしたければ，`plot(x, func(x))`とする必要があります．